# How does one define a well-ordering for the set of Zermelo ordinals?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For the von Neumann ordinals, $\in$ is the standard well-ordering.

I would like to know the standard way to define a well-ordering $<$ for the set of Zermelo ordinals.

In particular, I would like to know, for any two distinct Zermelo ordinals $u$ and $v$, how one determines, *formally*<sup>1</sup>, whether $u < v$ or $v < u$.

I assume that this definition of $<$ for Zermelo ordinals will depend only on Zermelo's axioms, with the possible addition of the Axiom of Foundation.  At any rate, I am interested only in such a definition.  (In particular, I would like to avoid any definition that requires the existence of the set $\omega$ of finite von Neumann ordinals.<sup>2</sup>)

---

In case the definition of Zermelo ordinals is not sufficiently standardized, below I give the one I know.

If $w$ is any set, let $\rho(w)$ be the formula that asserts $$\varnothing \in w \;\; \wedge \;\; \forall y\in w (\{y\} \in w).$$

Zermelo's original Axiom of Infinity postulates the existence of a set $w$ such that $\rho(w)$.

Let set $z$ be the smallest set $w$ such that $\rho(w)$ holds.  Formally, $$z := \bigcap \,\{w : \rho(w)\}.$$

A "Zermelo ordinal" is an element of the set $z$.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> I use the word "formally" here to rule out the method of "counting the number of curly braces." :)</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> On p. 42 of his [*The Foundations of Mathematics*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Foundations_of_Mathematics/_B_oQQAACAAJ?hl=en) Kenneth Kunen contrasts Zermelo's original Axiom of Infinity (Axiom des Unendlichen: $\exists w [\varnothing \in w \ \wedge \ \forall y\in w (\{y\} \in w)]$), which justifies the existence of the set of Zermelo ordinals, with the now more standard Axiom of Infinity ($\exists w [\varnothing \in w \ \wedge \ \forall y\in w (y \cup \{y\} \in w)]$), which justifies the existence of the set $\omega$ of finite von Neumman ordinals.  Kunen writes (my emphasis added):</sup>

> <sup>...the two Axioms of Infinity are equivalent, although one needs to use [the Axiom of] Replacement (*which Zermelo did not have*) to prove the equivalence...".</sup>

<sup>As an exercise, I would like to prove, using the Axiom of Replacement, that the existence of the set $z$ of Zermelo ordinals implies the existence of the set $\omega$ of finite von Neumman ordinals, but all my attempts stumble for not having a proper definition of a well-ordering for $z$.</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, we need to show that transitive closures (of relations) exist. This can be done using the axiom of the power set and $\Delta_0$ separation without reference to the axiom of infinity. It can also be done with full separation.

The transitive closure of $S \subseteq A^2$ is simply $\{(a, b) \in A^2 \mid \forall Q \subseteq A^2,$ if $Q$ is transitive and $S \subseteq Q$ then $(a, b) \in Q\}$. You can easily verify that the transitive closure is the smallest transitive relation containing $S$.

Then $< \subseteq z^2$ is the transitive closure of $\in_z = \{(a, b) \in z^2 \mid a \in b\}$. Since $\in_z$ is well-founded and the transitive closure of a well-founded relation is also well-founded, we see that $<$ is well-founded. The fact that $<$ is a strict total order can be shown using induction.

Edit: Here's a proof that the transitive closure of a well-founded relation is well-founded.

Consider any relation $\prec \subseteq S^2$, and let $<$ be its transitive closure. Prove that $x < y$ if and only if either $x \prec y$ or $\exists z \in S (z \prec y \land x < z)$. Dually, we see that $x < y$ if and only if either $x \prec y$ or $\exists z \in S (x \prec z \land z < y)$.

A set $Q \subseteq S$ is said to be "inductive" with respect to $\prec$ if $\forall x \in S (\{y \in S \mid y \prec x\} \subseteq Q \to x \in Q)$. Then $\prec$ is said to be a well-founded relation if for all $Q \subseteq S$ which are inductive with respect to $S$, $Q = S$. We are defining the term "well-founded" here using well-founded induction.

Now suppose that $\prec$ is well-founded. We wish to demonstrate that $<$ is also well-founded. Consider some $Q$ which is inductive with respect to $<$. Define $Q' = \{x \in S \mid \{y \in S \mid y < x\} \subseteq Q\}$. Note that $Q' \subseteq Q$.

I claim that $Q'$ is inductive with respect to $\prec$. For consider some arbitrary $x \in S$, and suppose $\{y \in S \mid y \prec x\} \subseteq Q'$. Now suppose we have some $y \in S$ with $y < x$. Then there are two cases. The first is that $y \prec x$; in this case, we have $y \in Q' \subseteq Q$. The second is that there is some $z \in S$ such that $z \prec x$ and $y < z$. In that case, we know that $z \in Q'$, and therefore $y \in Q$. So in either case, we know that $y \in Q$. Thus, we see that $\{y \in S \mid y < x\} \subseteq Q$. Therefore, $x \in Q'$.

Since $Q'$ is inductive with respect to $\prec$ and $\prec$ is well-founded, we have $Q' = S$. Then we have $S = Q' \subseteq Q \subseteq S$, so $Q = S$. $\square$

Now we show that any well-founded relation $\prec \subseteq S^2$ is irreflexive. Define $Q = \{x \in S \mid x \nprec x\}$; we will show that $Q$ is inductive. Now consider an arbitrary $x \in S$, and suppose $\{y \in S \mid y \prec x\} \subseteq Q$. Suppose $x \prec x$. Then $x \in Q$; that is, $x \nprec x$. This is a contradiction. Therefore, $x \nprec x$; that is, $x \in Q$. Since $Q$ is inductive, we have $Q = S$, so $S$ is irreflexive. $\square$

Let's return to our original topic, the relation $<$ on the Zermelo ordinals. We have shown that $<$ is well-founded and thus irreflexive. And of course it is transitive, being a transitive closure. All that remains is to show that $<$ is total.

We demonstrate $\forall a \in z \forall b \in z (a < b \lor a = b \lor b < a)$ by induction on $a$.

The base case is $\forall b \in z (0 < b \lor 0 = b \lor b < 0)$. We actually strengthen what must be proved to $\forall b \in z (0 < b \lor 0 = b)$; this follows immediately from induction on $b$.

For the inductive step, suppose $\forall b \in z (a < b \lor a = b \lor b < a)$. We wish to show that $\forall b \in z (Sa < b \lor Sa = b \lor b < Sa)$. Consider some $b \in z$. By the inductive hypothesis, we know that either $a < b$, $a = b$, or $b < a$. If $a = b$ or $b < a$, then clearly $b < Sa$. If $a < b$, then we have two possibilities. The first is that $a \in b$; in this case, we have $b = Sa$. The second is that there is some $c \in z$ such that $a \in c$ and $c < b$. In this case, we actually have $c = Sa$, and therefore $Sa < b$. This completes the proof. $\square$

Comment: Thanks!  This way of defining transitive closure is handier for this problem than the one that Kunnen gives, because it does not require the use of $\omega$ at all.  (Kunnen's is a recursive definition, and it does use $\omega$, though I suppose one could devise a similar definition that uses $z$ instead.)  Unfortunately, I can't come *even close* to filling the missing bits in your argument, to prove that $<$, as you defined it, is well-founded on $z$ and that it is a strict total order on $z$ (other than the by-construction fact that $<$ is transitive on $z$).  Can you point to a full proof?

Comment: @kjo I fleshed out the proof for you. You are correct that you run into a serious issue trying to define transitive closures in terms of the natural numbers if you only have $z$ and not $\omega$. You would like to define the transitive closure using finite sequences, but to discuss finite sequences, you would likely need to already have the $<$ operator in hand.

Comment: Thank you!  There's a lot of interesting mathematics in your post.  I did not know that way of defining well-foundedness.  It was not at all obvious to me that it was equivalent to the definition I knew; it was very illuminating for me to work out the proof of this equivalence.  I had not realized how much ground, mostly new to me, had to be covered to address my original question...  For one thing, I still feel a bit wobbly on the properties of a relation's transitive closure.  I will probably be posting some follow-up questions on this subject.  (More targeted, I hope!)  Thanks again!

Comment: @kjo A good question is one that raises more good questions. My definition of well-foundedness is more common among mathematicians who work with constructive logic, where you don’t assume $\forall P(P \lor \neg P)$. The traditional version of wellfoundedness is useless in this setting, since if we have a classically well-founded $\prec$ and any $a \prec b$, the law of excluded middle holds (by considering a set of the form $\{x \mid x =b \lor (x =a \land P)\}$, whose minimal element is either $a$ (meaning $P$ holds) or $b$ (meaning $\neg P$ holds). I’m glad you found the exercise illuminating.

Comment: Say, we define transfinite von-Neumann ordinals by taking unions at limit stages, is there any problem with that? Or does it work just fine?

Answer (score -3):

I am reading Kunen,The Foundations of Mathematics as well and this notes is originated from that remark as well. More concretely, I use Zermelo’s Axiom of Infinity to define omega (without Axiom of Foundations and Axiom of Replacement). There are some personal symbols which I think is still understandable. This notes answer the question about the process to establish well-ordering.

I do not think you can define z (the set of all finite Zermelo ordinals)in that way because apparently the class of all sets which satisfy rho is a proper class.

For the question about the equivalence of 2forms of Axiom of Infinity. It is obvious from the hints in the book I think.

https://www.overleaf.com/read/rmsznsvnnxsm